# Passing generic functions with paramaters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I think I might be retarded or I'm asking too much out of C# but I can't get this to work.

What essentially I'm trying to do is to wrap an API-client with some logging functions and a method to request a new token from the API-server.

**controller:**

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/model/get/{id}"]
    public IHttpActionResult GetModel<Model>(int id)
    {
        var result = Service.DoHttp<Model>(ServiceClass.GetModel, id);
    }
}
```

**service:**

```
public static class ServiceClass
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(Globals.ExternalApiPath) };

    private static string TokenHeader = "";

    public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetModel(int id)
    {
        var response = client.GetAsync($"/api/get/{id}");
        return await response;
    }

    public static T DoHttp<T>(Func<int, HttpResponseMessage> funk, int id)
    {
        try
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", TokenHeader);

            var result = funk(id);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(String.Format($"Unknown error! Unable to contact remote API! AccessToken: {TokenHeader} Status code: {result.StatusCode}"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // log ex
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

But my **Service.DoHttp(Service.GetModel, id);** complains about it being the wrong return type.

What am I doing wrong or have I misunderstood the whole concept?

EDIT: Compiler complains about *'Task ServiceClass.GetModel(int)' has the wrong return type*

Comment: Can you show us the exact text of the 'complaint'?

Comment: Added Visual Studios complaint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `DoHttp` method to the following.

```
public static T DoHttp<T>(Func<int, Task<HttpResponseMessage>> funk, int id)
```

As the `GetModel` method returns a `Task` you need to use a task as the return type of the `Func` too.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Jesus sometimes you feel stupid. Thanks!